# How to set correct hourly ticks of time-scale X-axis on chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I have a problem with chart.js (2.8.0). Probably I am doing something wrong, but can't find myself.

I want to set hourly ticks on time scale X-axis and set the `time` as

```
unit: 'hour',
displayFormats: { hour: 'HH:MM'}
```

I expected to have x-axis ticks such as 18:00, 19:00, 20:00, ...
However what I got is 18:01, 19:01, 20:01, ...

How can I correct and remove this extra one minute?

My html file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="canvas-container" style="width: 400px">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and script.js is as follows:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
var myData = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
                {x:'2019-01-01 18:20', y:20},
                {x:'2019-01-01 19:50', y:45},
                {x:'2019-01-01 21:15', y:25},
                {x:'2019-01-01 21:45', y:30}
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                position: 'bottom',
                time: {
                    unit: 'hour',
                    displayFormats: {
                        hour: 'HH:MM'
                    },
                    min: '2019-01-01 18:00',
                    max: '2019-01-01 22:00'
                },
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, myData);
```

Comment: Don't add an answer to the question, add it as a self answer.

Comment: A simple lookup would have told you that date/time formatting is case sensitive, and `MM` represents months, not minutes.

Comment: Thanks. HH:MM should be HH:mm. This solved the problem.